# I keep getting -1 in my tree even though I check the bounds for it while implementing Prim's for maze generation

Tags: java, maze, prims-algorithm

So in the value of my nodes I keep getting numbers that go out of bounds of where I check the bounds. Here is the algorithm:

```
    public void prims(Node parentNode, ArrayList<Node> frontiers){

    Node rootNode = parentNode;
    Node newTile;
    Node tempParent;
    ArrayList<Node> children;


    if(frontiers == null){
        frontiers = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    int x = parentNode.getValue().getX();
    int y = parentNode.getValue().getY();

    isRevealed[x][y] = true;

    addFrontier(x-1, y, frontiers, parentNode);
    addFrontier(x+1, y, frontiers, parentNode);
    addFrontier(x, y-1, frontiers, parentNode);
    addFrontier(x, y+1, frontiers, parentNode);

    while(!frontiers.isEmpty()){
        newTile = frontiers.get((int)(frontiers.size()*Math.random()));

        x = newTile.getValue().getX();
        y = newTile.getValue().getY();
        if(x < 0){
            int i = 9;
        }

        isRevealed[x][y] = true;

        children = newTile.getChildren();
        if(children.size() != 0){
            tempParent = children.get((int)(children.size()*Math.random()));
            newTile.clearChildren();
            tempParent.addChild(newTile);
            if(newTile.getValue().getX() < 0){
                int j = 0;
            }
        }

        frontiers.remove(newTile);

        addFrontier(x-1, y, frontiers, newTile);
        addFrontier(x+1, y, frontiers, newTile);
        addFrontier(x, y-1, frontiers, newTile);
        addFrontier(x, y+1, frontiers, newTile);



    }


}

public void addFrontier(int x, int y, ArrayList<Node> frontiers, Node parent){

    Node frontier = new Node(new Point2D(x,y), parent);

    //TODO check if x and y correspond to height and width properly (in case it isn't working for some reason)
    if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < width && y < height){
        if(isRevealed[x][y]){
            return;
        }
        if(frontiers.contains(frontier)){
            for(Node node : frontiers){
                if(node.equals(frontier)){
                    node.addChild(parent);
                }
            }
        }else{
            frontier.addChild(parent);
            frontiers.add(frontier);
        }
    }

}
```

Node and Point2D are custom classes I made for the purpose of completing this algorithm. The problem that I am experience is that in "addFrontier" class I check if the values are within the bounds but when I put a break point and check the children of the root node I get -1,0 1,0 0,-1 0,1 in that order. I am also noticing that when I draw it out in the GUI, I get a graph that looks just like grid lines rather than a spanning tree.

If I need to add any information please let me know.

Also note that the Node class checks if a node is trying to add a child that has itself as its parent. Also the equals method of the Node class only checks if the value is the same of the two nodes.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question with the information you have given. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, the `Node` constructor seems to take a parent `Node` as a parameter, but it is not clear if the constructor will add the newly constructed `Node` to the list of children of the parent. If this is the case, it seems wrong that in `addFrontier` the new `Node` is constructed before the bounds check. But without seeing the full code, this is just a guess.